# Database design that requires two searches

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, database-design

I have played around with mongodb in the past, but this is the first time I am working on a project.

I am designing a Spanish dictionary. However I am having trouble with the design. This is the first design. These are the objects that get stored in mongodb.

**Dictionary collection**

```
{
    word:"comer",
    type:"infinitive",
   Definition:"A definiition for the word hablar",
    conjugation: {
        present: ["como", "comes", "come", "comemos", "coméis", "comen"],
        preterite:["comí", "comiste", "comió", "comimos", "comisteis", "comieron"],
    }
},
// Lets pretend that this is another verb with different conjugation forms.
{
    word:"hablar",
    type:"infinitive",
   Definition:"A definiition for the word hablar",
    conjugation: {
        present: ["como", "comes", "come", "comemos", "coméis", "comen"],
        preterite:["comí", "comiste", "comió", "comimos", "comisteis", "comieron"],
    }
}
```

With this design I can search for a word by comparing the **word:"a word"** property. The problem is that with this design searching for "como" isn't posible or at least not efficient.

The second design has two collections **Words** and **verbs**

**Words**

```
{
    word:"como",
    infinitive:"comer",
},
{
    word:"comer",
    infinitive:"comer",
},
{
    word:"comemos",
    infinitive:"comer",
},
{
    word:"habla",
    infinitive:"hablar",
}
```

**Verbs**

```
{
    word:"comer",
    Definition:"A definiition for the word comer",
    conjugation: {
        present: ["como", "comes", "come", "comemos", "coméis", "comen"],
        preterite:["comí", "comiste", "comió", "comimos", "comisteis", "comieron"],
    }
},
{
    word:"hablar",
    Definition:"A definiition for the word hablar",
    conjugation: {
        present: ["como", "comes", "come", "comemos", "coméis", "comen"],
        preterite:["comí", "comiste", "comió", "comimos", "comisteis", "comieron"],
    }
}
```

With this design any word can be easily searched. Then the **infinitive** property can be used to search the **Verbs** collection.

The problem now is that two searches are required to find a word. What is worse is that to find an infinitive like the word **comer** you first search the **words** Collection to find the same word **comer** before looking it up in the **Verbs** collection.

**The questions**

Is it unusual to have to perform two searches to find a word?

Is this a bad design or can it be improved?

Can I design this such that only one search is required.

**Note:**

I understand that data can be stored in multiple collections and as such multiple searches may be required. But this is different since one search must be done before searching multiple collections to get the information we require.

Comment: With the _first_ design why do you think _"... The problems is that with this design searching for "como" isn't possible or at least not efficient."_ Have you tried any queries or created any indexes on the collection? What would be the most used  queries might look like?

Comment: You can easily and efficiently search "como" as `dictionary.find({$or: [{word: "como"}, {"conjugation.present": "como"}, {"conjugation.preterite": "como"}]})` with first "design".

Comment: @Prasad There can be many words with the same name, and it's  my understanding that in these conditions indexing isn't recommended. Or am i misunderstanding the way indexing works?

Comment: @Alex Blex Can you explain a bit more about how this is efficient? To me this is like a linear search,searching the conjugation field of each word in turn.

Comment: _"There can be many words with the same name, and it's my understanding that in these conditions indexing isn't recommended."_ Yes, there can be many words with same name; but, indexing is for efficient or a fast search.

Comment: Please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with your first design by using the [Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search) feature of the MongoDB.

First we create a compound index on the fields we want to search:

```js
db.dictionaries.createIndex(
   {
     "word": "text",
     "conjugation.present": "text",
     "conjugation.preterite": "text"
   }
 )
```

Then we can use $text query operator like this:

```js
db.dictionaries.find(
    { $text: { $search: "comen" } },
    { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
  ).sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } });
```

`$text` will tokenize the search string using whitespace and most punctuation as delimiters, and perform a logical OR of all such tokens in the search string.

Let's assume you have those documents in the collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5df8bb67646b812758d7e6c5"),
    "conjugation": {
      "present": [ "como", "comes", "come", "comemos", "coméis", "comen" ],
      "preterite": [ "comí", "comiste", "comió", "comimos", "comisteis", "comieron" ]
    },
    "word": "comer",
    "type": "infinitive",
    "definition": "A definition for the word comer"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5df8bb9f646b812758d7e6c6"),
    "conjugation": {
      "present": [ "como", "comes", "come", "comemos", "coméis", "comen" ],
      "preterite": [ "comí", "comiste", "comió", "comimos", "comisteis", "comieron" ]
    },
    "word": "hablar",
    "type": "infinitive",
    "definition": "A definition for the word hablar"
  }
]
```

When we search by "comer", only the first document will be found.

When we search by "hablar", only the second document will be found.

When we search by "como" both documents will be found.

You can even specify a [language](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/) for Text Index, and Spanish is one of the supported languages.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the link below to know how you can query an array in MongoDB https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/.